# HTML5 ContentEditable

Tags: php, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a few questions regarding HTML5 ContentEditable and PHP,  I would be very happy if you could provide me with examples of what I am trying to do so I can get an idea.

- I have a website that I would like to edit but only if "Admin"is logged in - I can do the login side of things but I am unsure how to code the HTML5 ContentEditable into it so that it does not load when "Admin" is not logged in.
- How would I save content that is changed in HTML5 ContentEditable?

Comment: Part one: `<?php if ($current_user->isAdmin) { echo 'contenteditable'; } ?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would I save content that is changed in HTML5 ContentEditable?

Assuming that you have a div that's `contentEditable`, like:

```
<div id="content" contentEditable="true">here goes your contenteditable content</div>
```

After you've finished editing (like when you're clicking the save-button) you have to do something like this (with `jQuery`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post('save.php', {
    content : $('#content').html()
}
</script>
```

You'd then receive a post request with you save.php script. You can access the posted data using `$_POST['content'];`

Comment: Should it redirect to save.php?